# MS Access Error Trapping

Tags: ms-access

Please, I have limited logic capability on this.

The text boxes for search criteria and the SEARCH button are on the main form while the search results are on a pop up form.

I do not want the details form to open if the provided criteria does not match with any record in the database. Instead I want the error message "Sorry, no search criteria" to pop up, but in my current state when there are no matching results/no criteria the details form still opens with some records together with the error message.

Here is the code behind the SEARCH button:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Msg

If Not IsNull(Me.Form) Then

    DoCmd.OpenForm "f_search"
    ' Update the record source
    Forms.f_search!f_search_sub.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM q_vehicles " & BuildFilter

    Me.Requery
Else

Exit_btnSearch_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Msg:
MsgBox "Sorry, no search criteria.", vbInformation, "MV Clearance"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Error handling needs improvement, objects need closing -- please see detail under answer from J. Bones.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do a search **first**, and then open the form only if that search returns results:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim db as Database
On Error GoTo Err_Msg

Set db = CurrentDB

If Not IsNull(Me.Form) Then
    'First open the recordset
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM q_vehicles " & BuildFilter & "")

    'Check to make sure the recordset isn't empty.  If it is, exit the sub
    If rec.EOF = true then
        GoTo Err_Msg
    EndIf

    DoCmd.OpenForm "f_search"
    ' Update the record source
    Forms.f_search!f_search_sub.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM q_vehicles " & BuildFilter

    Me.Requery
Else

Exit_btnSearch_Click:
    Set db = Nothing
    Set rec = Nothing
Exit Sub

Err_Msg:
MsgBox "Sorry, no search criteria.", vbInformation, "MV Clearance"
End If
GoTo Exit_btnSearch_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I urge you to close the `rec` and `db` objects.  Best accomplished right before `Exit Sub` ... use of `Resume` just after the message will facilitate that.

Comment: Good catch, @Smandoli.  I normally do that but missed it, I have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Looks great.  +1.  Might need `rec.Close`.